# post visibility history

Tags: revisions

Revisions show past versions of the article/page but is there a way of seeing the Visibility status historically?

User A publishes 
User B edits the published page changing the visibility to something like private

Is this reflected anywhere in the history/revisions?

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress can display changes in post content, by using the [post revisions feature](https://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-revisions/). 
WordPress can however not by default show any changes in post status (or publish date, or author, etc.).

However there are plugins that can solve this. I built one myself called [Simple History](http://simple-history.com/) that displays more information about the changes that have been made to a post, including post status (and publish date, and author, etc.).

Here's a screenshot showing that it is possible to see that a post have been published by one user, and then set to private by another user.

[image: Screenshot of plugin Simple History that shows the difference between two post edits]

Hope this helps.